# Query object with max field on MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-charts

I am new to MongoDB and I use Atlas & Charts in order to query and visualize the results.
I want to create a graph that shows the max amount of money every day, and indicate the person with the max amount of money.

for example:
if my collection contains the following documents:

```
{"date": "15-12-2020", "name": "alice", "money": 7}
{"date": "15-12-2020", "name": "bob", "money": 9}
{"date": "16-12-2020", "name": "alice", "money": 39}
{"date": "16-12-2020", "name": "bob", "money": 25}
```

what should be the query I put on query box (on "Charts") in order to create a graph with the following result?

```
date        |   max_money |     the_person_with_max_money

15-12-2020          9               bob
16-12-2020          39              alice
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use an `aggregation` and I think this should works.

First of all `$sort` values by `money` (I'll explain later why).

And then use `$group` to group values by `date`.

The query looks like this:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$sort": { "money": -1 }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$date",
      "max_money": { "$max": "$money" },
      "the_person_with_max_money": { "$first": "$name" }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pqHyowSNh9m)

How this works? Well, there is a "problem" using `$group`, is that you can't keep values for the next stage unless you uses an accumulator, so, the best way it seems is to use `$first` to get the first name.
And this is why is sorted by `money` descendent, to get the name whose `money` value is the greatest at first position.

So, sorting we ensure that the first value is what you want.

And then using `group` to group the documents with the same `date` and create the fields `max_money` and `the_person_with_max_money`.

Comment: Thank you! it works! another question though, if I want to generalize it and get not only the max one, but the top-n for every date, how can I do it?

Comment: for example getting the top-2 will return: {"date": "15-12-2020", "name": "bob", "money": 9}
{"date": "15-12-2020", "name": "alice", "money": 7}
{"date": "16-12-2020", "name": "alice", "money": 39}
{"date": "16-12-2020", "name": "bob", "money": 25}

Comment: Is [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/WIjdoGadCZG) you expected? I've used `2` into `$slice`. You can use another number to get the top-n. Also the same values but with another output format [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gzXNQ4tKr2k). The first example has an array to store the N  values and the second example divide the array and output differents objects.

Comment: Amazing. Thank you!